# Reverse Bernoulli inequality for scaled variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $0\leq x\leq 1/2$ and $1\leq n\in \mathbb{Z}$. From Bernoulli's inequality we know that $$\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\geq 1-x.$$ Is it possible to show a reverse bound if we allow $x$ to be scaled:$$\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\leq 1-\frac{x}{2}?$$ This doesn't seem to be covered by Bernoulli's inequality or any other basic inequalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. For any $n\geq 1$,
$$ f_n(x) = \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n $$
is a convex decreasing function on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, and $a_n=f_n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is an increasing sequence converging to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$, hence it follows that:

$$ \forall x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right],\qquad f_n(x)\leq 1-\left(2-\frac{2}{\sqrt{e}}\right)x\leq 1-\frac{7x}{9}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It is also known that $$\left(1-\frac{x}n \right)^n \leq e^{-x}$$